# Is there a way to replay old sketches on my Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I naturally think of sketches like SMSs - you have a sequence of the old ones lying around you can peruse.

The other model of online messaging is snapchat, where your messages disappear after sending.

I've got a couple of sketches from a friend I'd like to replay - I'm wondering if this is possible, or I'm just thinking in the 'wrong model'.

My question is: **Is there a way to replay old sketches on my Apple Watch?**